# How can I make VIM a full fledged IDE

Tags: vim, ide

How could I make VIM a full fledged IDE by using different supported plugins for YUI, JQuery and git integration etc.

Comment: Please [don't crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206469/how-can-i-make-vim-a-full-fledged-ide. I'm going to close here; if you want it here flag the SO version and ask them to migrate

Comment: Posted also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58730/how-can-i-make-vim-a-full-fledged-ide

Answer (score 0):

While there are many plugins for Vim, it really isn't an IDE. However, you *can* get many of the features of IDEs in Vim.

As you mentioned, you can install plugins manually by searching for them based on features you'd like. If you are looking for something that is already mostly configured, then I'd suggest using [scrooloose's vimfiles](https://github.com/scrooloose/vimfiles) project hosted on GitHub. You can clone it into your ~/.vim:

```
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/vimfiles.git ~/.vim
```

You may want to backup your current `~/.vim` directory first.

Once it is downloaded you can install the submodules:

```
cd ~/.vim
git submodule init && git submodule update
```

Finally to use the new plugins you'll have to source the vimrc file in your `~/.vimrc` by adding `source ~/.vim/vimrc` to your `~/.vimrc`.